# Using Perl's regular expression to find items

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, text-processing

I have a set up Perl scripts I use to retrieve data from a text file, but one thing that will not show up is anything that starts with an asterisk.  Here's the code I have:

```
while(<INFILE>) {
   chomp $_;

    if (m/^\s*$/) {
        next;
    }

    my @fields = split(/\  /,$_);
    my @output;

    foreach my $field(@fields) {
        if($field =~ /^\*?[ABMQRWY][A-Z0-9]{4}235 / ) {
            push @output,$field;
        }
    }
}
```

My if statement grabs everything that is 8 characters long, but sometimes there's an * in front of jobs that it will not pull.  How do I include that?  I know I need to escape it, but not sure where to put it.

Here's some examples of the data I'm pulling:

```
W50DW235 DW
M50DW235 DW
Q0608235 08
APJ40235 40
M3515235 15
M34DW235 DW
M3408235 08
RES08235 08
BSP20235 20
W1208235 08
B3008235 08
```

This is raw lines from the file:

```
18122/0655 18122/0700  W50DW235 DW        LEV001  002  D50DW235
18122/0735 18122/0740  M50DW235 DW        LEV002  002  W50DW235
```

The line it won't pull from with an asterisk is like this:

```
18123/0300 18123/0400 *D1708235 08        LEV001  001
```

In order to pull the data, I use the following which catches the items with a two space break:

```
my @fields = split(/\  /,$_);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some example data. It would also be nice if your code was indented to make it more readable. Your pattern looks fine for what you describe. Problem must be that your data is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: When `*` gets included, it will match nine characters not 8? check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/LXSqEs/1)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50159742/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the asterisk!  The asterisked item is `*D1708235`, but your regex requires the first alphabetic character to be `[ABMQRWY]`, which does not include `D`.

That said, here's a cleaned-up example:

```
my @output;

while(<>) {
    chomp;                       # Don't need to specify $_ - it's the default
    next if /^\s*$/;             # Ditto, and the single-line form for readability
    #print;     # If you want to see what it's doing

    my @fields = split;          # Split $_ on whitespace-separated fields

    foreach my $field (@fields) {
        #print "-$field-\n";
        push @output, $field     # Again, single-line form
            if $field =~ /^\*?[ABDMQRWY][A-Z0-9]{4}235/;
    }                         #  ^ the missing link   ^ no trailing whitespace
}

print "Results:\n", join("\n", @output), "\n";
```

I removed the trailing whitespace from the `$field` regex because the `split` will produce fields that have neither leading nor trailing whitespace.

Input:

```
W50DW235 DW
M50DW235 DW
Q0608235 08
APJ40235 40
M3515235 15
M34DW235 DW
M3408235 08
RES08235 08
BSP20235 20
W1208235 08
B3008235 08

18122/0655 18122/0700 W50DW235 DW LEV001 002 D50DW235
18122/0735 18122/0740 M50DW235 DW LEV002 002 W50DW235

18123/0300 18123/0400 *D1708235 08 LEV001 001
```

Output:

```
Results:
W50DW235
M50DW235
Q0608235
APJ40235
M3515235
M34DW235
M3408235
RES08235
BSP20235
W1208235
B3008235
W50DW235
D50DW235
M50DW235
W50DW235
*D1708235
```

Comment: Well, it sort of worked this morning.  :-).  All good.  I run the above results through a cross reference file where everything was failing because I had system, the two digits on the right in the file.  Had one file I was testing without those that I copied back and it all worked..  Again, thanks for your help.  Kind of streamlined that script a little.

Comment: Made one final change to get it to display like before.  Took this:     print "Results:\n", join("\n", @output), "\n";, and changed it to this: print OUTFILE join("\n", @output), "\n";
print join("\n", @output), "\n";